# how to redirect traffic from Http to Https in Phoenix Elixir for SSL on Load Balancer?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I need to forward the traffic from Http to Https, SSL is on the load balancer so all I need to do is forward the header by using the `plug_ssl` so in my `prod.exs` I added:

```
config :web, Web.Endpoint,
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]]
```

in my `prod.exs` and remove everything else on `config :web, Web.Endpoint`

It doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Do I need to put the `force_ssl` in my `router`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to enable the `force_ssl` plug only for your endpoints that are not used for health check or something related to that.

I had a similar problem with the k8s Ingress on GKE and the solution was to put the `force_ssl` **on router** only for my application routes, and let `/healthz` (which was configured as my health check route) using HTTP.

An example of `config/prod.exs`:

```elixir
# Tells if we need to enforce SSL for our endpoints.
# Only production/staging should enforce
config :my_app, force_ssl: true

config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  load_from_system_env: true,
  url: [host: "${APP_HOST}", port: 80],
  server: true,
  http: [port:  "${PORT}"],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "${APP_HOST}", port: 443],
  secret_key_base: "${SECRET_KEY_BASE}"
```

And here is an example of `lib/my_app_web/router.ex`:

```elixir
defmodule MyAppWeb.Router do
  use MyAppWeb, :router

  # This route will NOT enforce SSL
  get("/healthz", MyAppWeb.HealthCheckController, :show)

  pipeline :api do
    plug(:accepts, ["json"])

    if Application.get_env(:my_app, :force_ssl) do
      plug(Plug.SSL, rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto], host: nil)
    end
  end

  scope "/", MyAppWeb do
    pipe_through(:api)

    # My routes will go here, and will be enforced if the
    # application flag `force_ssl` is enabled.
  end
end
```

This is a little bit tricky to debug. If you are using `kubernetes`, try to use the `kubectl describe ingress YOUR-INGRESS-HERE`, and always check the headers for your requests and responses while doing the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Usually healthchecker calls your server directly using local network, not the domain your app is on. This way you can put your local address into `exclude` option.

This is what I did:

```elixir
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto], exclude: ["localhost", "${IP_ADDRESS}"]],
```

Where `IP_ADDRESS` I got from environement variable (it depends on your deployment type on how you obtain it) using `distillery`. However when you don't use `distillery` you can just obtain environement variables this way:

```elixir
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto], exclude: ["localhost", System.get_env("IP_ADDRESS")]],
```